# Image thresholding using NEON instructions

Tags: iphone, ios, c, assembly, neon

I'm working on some image processing app for an iOS and thresholding is really a huge bottleneck. So I'm trying to optimize it using NEON. Here is the C version of function. Is there any way to rewrite this using NEON (unfortunately I have absolutely no experience in this) ?

```
static void thresh_8u( const Image& _src, Image& _dst, uchar thresh, uchar maxval, int type ) {
    int i, j;
    uchar tab[256];
    Size roi = _src.size();
    roi.width *= _src.channels();

    memset(&tab[0], 0, thresh);
    memset(&tab[thresh], maxval, 256-thresh);

    for( i = 0; i < roi.height; i++ ) {
        const uchar* src = (const uchar*)(_src.data + _src.step*i);
        uchar* dst = (uchar*)(_dst.data + _dst.step*i);
        j = 0;

        for(; j <= roi.width; ++j) {
            dst[j] = tab[src[j]];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, just do a `VCGT` with the threshold and then `VAND` it with maxval. Unfortunately I don't know enough ARM and NEON to turn it into something complete.

Comment: [This guide to NEON on iOS](http://wanderingcoder.net/2010/06/02/intro-neon/) may be helpful, along with [a few things iOS developers ought to know about ARM](http://wanderingcoder.net/2010/07/19/ought-arm/). They don't solve your exact problem but may give you somewhere to start investigating.

Comment: Shouldn't the condition in the nested loop be "j < roi.width"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's actually pretty easy, if you can make sure your rows are always a multiple of 16 bytes wide, because the compiler (clang) has special types representing the NEON vector registers, and knows how to apply the normal C operators to them.  Here's my little test function:

```
#ifdef __ARM_NEON__

#include <arm_neon.h>

void computeThreshold(void *input, void *output, int count, uint8_t threshold, uint8_t highValue) {
    uint8x16_t thresholdVector = vdupq_n_u8(threshold);
    uint8x16_t highValueVector = vdupq_n_u8(highValue);
    uint8x16_t *__restrict inputVector = (uint8x16_t *)input;
    uint8x16_t *__restrict outputVector = (uint8x16_t *)output;
    for ( ; count > 0; count -= 16, ++inputVector, ++outputVector) {
        *outputVector = (*inputVector > thresholdVector) & highValueVector;
    }
}

#endif
```

This operates on 16 bytes at a time.  A `uint8x16_t` is a vector register containing 16 8-bit unsigned ints.  The `vdupq_n_u8` returns a vector `uint8x16_t` filled with 16 copies of its argument.

The `>` operator, applied to two `uint8x16_t` values, does 16 comparisons between pairs of 8-bit unsigned ints.  Where the left input is greater than the right input, it returns 0xff (which is different from a normal C `>`, which just returns 0x01).  Where the left input is less than or equal to the right input, it returns 0.  (It compiles into the VCGT.U8 instruction.)

The `&` operator, applied to two `uint8x16_t` values, computes the boolean AND of 128 pairs of bits.

The loop compiles to this in a release build:

```
0x6e668:  vldmia r2, {d4, d5}
0x6e66c:  subs   r0, #16
0x6e66e:  vcgt.u8 q10, q10, q8
0x6e672:  adds   r2, #16
0x6e674:  cmp    r0, #0
0x6e676:  vand   q10, q10, q9
0x6e67a:  vstmia r1, {d4, d5}
0x6e67e:  add.w  r1, r1, #16
0x6e682:  bgt    0x6e668
```